# jQuery: Any better way to write this block of .each()?

Tags: jquery

```
$('.list-links-nested a').each(function(){      
  currentPage(this);
});

$("#menu-main > li > a").each(function(){
  currentPage(this);  
});

$("#menu-sub a").each(function(){      
  currentPage(this);        
});
```

Any suggestion on how to write it better instead of repeating the function called?

Updated code and it works:

```
var links = $(".list-links-nested a, #menu-main > li > a");
links.each(currentPage);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a comma in your string to provide multiple selectors.

```
$(".list-links-nested a, #menu-main > li > a, #menu-sub a").each(currentPage);
```

You can also pass `currentPage` as an argument itself and use `this` directly, instead of the argument you were passing.

Comment: It works if you make the change I mentioned - using `this` in `currentPage` instead of passing it through an anonymous function.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery allows multiple selectors separated with a comma (".class1,.class2")

reference: http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

```
 $("#menu-sub a,#menu-main > li > a,.list-links-nested a").each(function(){      
      currentPage(this);        
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

According to: http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

```
$('.list-links-nested a,#menu-main > li > a,#menu-sub a').each(function(){      
  currentPage(this);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use commas in your CSS selector to select multiple things at once, see http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#grouping:

```
$('.list-links-nested a, #menu-main > li > a, #menu-sub a').each(function(){      
  currentPage(this);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".list-links-nested a, #menu-main > li > a, #menu-sub a").each(function() {
  currentPage(this);
});
```

Ref: [Multi Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)